# Error in Localhost

Tags: php

I have code in index.php

```
<?php $title ="League of Draven" ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/inc/head.php';?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/inc/menu.php';?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/inc/footer.php';?>
```

in head.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> <?php print $title ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

when i try to open in my browser i find this error:

```
 Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/inc/head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myshop\index.php on line 6

 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/inc/head.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Myshop\index.php on line 6
```

Comment: I dont see a `require_once` in your example. At least show the relevant code or we cannot help we are not **clairvoyant**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you have not created a Virtual Host for this project, so the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` will be pointing at `C:\xampp\htdocs\` and not `C:\xampp\htdocs\Myshop`

To avoid this you can use the following which says require from the `inc` folder below where I am currently running this code from whereever that may be

```
<?php 
    $title ="League of Draven"
    require_once './inc/head.php';
    require_once './inc/menu.php';
    require_once './inc/footer.php';
```

Comment: thats not working too. I have created a folder Myshop (index.php file here) in htdoc folder. In Myshop i have created another folder inc in which i have placed head.php file.

Comment: See amended answer